# *.vue files, Visual Studio 2017 & TypeScript

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to edit [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/)'s *.vue component files in Visual Studio 2017 with highlighting and intellisense support for HTML, TypeScript AND SCSS?

At the moment, I'm separating the different sections to different files:

```
<!-- my-component.vue opened in HTML editor -->
<template>
    <div> text </div>
</template>
<script src="./path/to/my-component.ts"></script>
<style src="./path/to/my-component.scss"></style>
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm still struggling to get SCSS support for .vue single file component files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently the answer is no.  The HTML editor is aware of some languages that can be hosted, such as CSS, JavaScript, and Razor (ASP.NET).  In these cases, the editor does some fancy things to map sections of the text to each language service.  However, TypeScript and SCSS do not support that at the moment, and as far as I know it's not on the backlog for either team.

Please request this using the VS Feedback tool.  Since vuejs support this, it bears some weight and may get taken into account for future feature planning.  A customer report can sometimes carry more weight than mine.

(Full Disclosure: I work on the team that owns the HTML and SCSS editors in VS.  We don't own TypeScript, but we work with the team for things like this.)

Comment: Hey @Jimmy Any updates on this from MS? Any backlog updates?

Comment: @PaulLemke Unfotunately, it's still not a high priority feature at this time.  I couldn't find an active VS Feedback request on this topic, so I still recommend filing one.  If it gets enough votes, that can bump the priority up.

Comment: Looks like one was already created: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18837022-support-vue-file-intellisense-in-visual-studio

Comment: @PaulLemke The UserVoice suggestions always don't get routed to the feature teams.  The in-product VS Feedback is the better place to request this, as those items get tracked directly in our work item database.

Comment: @Jimmy any changes now with VS2019 around the corner?

Answer (score 8):

After some time, I actually have it all set up in Visual Studio 2017. (Everything except scss)

Here is what I did:

1. Install `vue-cli`
2. Install `VuePack` - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack-18329
3. Run this line in command prompt: 
   `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`
4. In command prompt, go to the directory where you want to create your application and run this:

   `dotnet new vue`

   `npm install`

   This will create the project for you. You can now open the project/add the project in Visual studio 2017.

   However the compiler did not recognize `.vue` files. I had to add one more manual step:
5. In the root of the application there is a file `webpack.config.js`, look for module => rules, you need to add a new rule:

   `{ 
      test: /\.vue$/, 
      include: /ClientApp/, 
      loader: 'vue-loader', 
      options: { 
        loaders: { 
          js: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' 
        } 
      }
    },`
6. After this I ran into some TypeScript compilation errors - the application would just get stuck on `Loading...` - to fix this you need to edit `tsconfig.json` - add the following:

   `"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
     "useWebpackText": true,
     "useCache": true,
     "useTranspileModule": true
   }`

After this I ran the project without issues.

---

Other interesting resources that can help you:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1383/modern-web-dev-aspnet-core-webpack-vuejs

https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2016/10/03/vue2-ts2/

Comment: This creates a new .net core project. Do you know how to enable the highlight also for existing MVC.NET project?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but have you ever got a linter working for vue files in Visual Studio 2017 or '19?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same difficulty, I end up using Visual Studio Code editor for **Vue** files and installed this plugin, named **Vetur**: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur
You can install it by searching on the extensions on the side menu of Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

i open it in vs code using the django template extension. and it seems to work, i know it is a different language, but it works in linting and auto formating

Answer (score 0):

There is a Vue plugin for Visual Studio called VuePack that will provide a better dev experience for single page vue files "*.vue" located here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack-18329

Comment: VuePack doesn't support typescript. It's basic intellisense. Not the full blown TypeScript experience we'd expect.

Comment: Quite right.  FYI, it appears after last VS update 15.5.2 VuePack has become unstable. Vetur is the way to go if you're using VSCode. I hope Microsoft supports the full VueJS story in the near future because attempting to get things going in VS 2017 with VueJs + TypeScript + SystemJs is a NIGHTMARE. The only started that I found that works in VS 2017 here: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now claims that Typescript inside  in .vue files is supported by Visual Studio 2017: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351510/support-vue-file-intellisense-in-visual-studio.html

indeed I tried it and (after some file reloading) syntax highlighting for html code and for Typescript, as well as intellisense works fine. Still trying to figure out how to convince compiler to produce .js files...