# VS2017 Javascript Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, javascript-intellisense

I working on a ASP.NET project with VueJs and I noticed that intellisense don't work.

I installed via bower the packages

- jquery
- bootstrap
- vue
- font-awesome

I installed via npm

- Lodash
- Webpack
- [loaders and others]

When I create a new javascript file (.js or .vue) and type

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

The intellisense **know** the `'jquery'` import, but when I type

```
$.
```

Raise a popup

> Intellisense is unable to determine the accurancy of this completition
>   item

I know that on VS2017 there are a new feature called [Salsa](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Salsa-Preview-in-Visual-Studio-15-Preview) 
that automatically download the .d.ts @types for intellisense.

The setting is under Tools -> Options -> Javascript/Typescript -> Language Service => Enable the new Javascript language service

I verified the presence of the .d.ts files on the folder indicated by the article (**%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript**)

I don't have the tsconfig.json

Any advice for the intellisense ?
There some advice working with .vue files ?
More in general there any link or documentation about the intellisense on Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already answered about importing jquery properly. If you want to work with `.vue` files in Visual Studio 2017 take a look at my step-by-step process:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775354/643761

Basically, you first setup the environment - including the use of VuePack2017 - that allows you to have intellisense in `.vue` files.