# Visual Studio 2017 Asp.Net Core 2.1 TypeScript Vue Setup - Not SPA

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-2017

I have been researching this for weeks now (off and on) trying to setup a new project that uses the latest versions of Visual Studio, Vue, TypeScript and .Net Core as of today (05/15/2018).  I do not need (nor want in this instance) to create a SPA application.  So my .cshtml pages will at least have a  tag that loads the specific file for that page.  Sure, it may have one for Vue and/or Require.js?

I am having a hard time completely configuring Visual Studio to take .ts files and transpile them into .js files using the new ES6 coding styles with `require` and such.

Some of the more useful links I have attempted to incorporate were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775354/373438) and another [here](https://github.com/billti/SimpleVueApp).  Seems like perhaps .Net Core 2.1 may have changed things?  I am also used to traditional .js files only.  Many references to Visual Studio Code, but that is not an option here.

This seems like a simple task.  NPM seems to download the internet into the project, but if it works, I'll take it.  Just at my wits end here.  What I would love is a step by step guide on creating a new VS project all the way to configuring the tsconfig.json and Webpack.config.js (if that is the best way to go) to having just a simple Vue app that displays "way to go dumbass!" for all I care.  First 2 beers on me for the person who can write it up or get me to a link that does what I need in the current versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use the awesome [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/) with [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices).

Follow these steps:

1. `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`
2. `npm install -D aspnet-webpack`
3. `npm install -D webpack-hot-middleware`
4. And add the Webpack middleware

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
        HotModuleReplacement = true,
        HotModuleReplacementClientOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
            { "reload", "true" }, 
        },
        ConfigFile = "node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js",
    });
}
```

For the moment I don't how to make HotModuleReplacement work without reloading.

5. Depending on your `vue.config.js` you can add js/css like this in the `_Layout.cshtml` for example

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/app.js" asp-append-version="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Production">
    <script src="~/bundle/js/chunk-vendors.js" asp-append-version="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/bundle/js/app.js" asp-append-version="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
```

6. Finally you could organize the Vue files like this to have a better intellisense. It works great with [Vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) for VSCode or non official extensions for VS2017.

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ...
</style>

<script lang="ts" src="./MyComponent.ts">
</script>
```

MyComponent.ts

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to move away from the TypeScript for the current project but this answer looks promising!