# asp.net-core 2.1 with Razor + vue+ webpack on a non-spa multi-page application

Tags: razor, vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack, multi-page-application

I am trying to setup an application using asp.net-core 2.1 with Razor using webpack and Vue.js in the front-end.

The project is a multi-page non-spa enterprise application (you can think of AirBNB style), and it is important to use server-side routing for SEO and code maintainability.

I came across some questions about how to setup a project like this

[Visual Studio 2017 Asp.Net Core 2.1 TypeScript Vue Setup - Not SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351120/visual-studio-2017-asp-net-core-2-1-typescript-vue-setup-not-spa)

and template projects like this

https://github.com/mrityunjaya-kumar/AspNetCore-Vue-Starter

My question is what are the pros & cons on this type of setup and if there is a better setup for this type of application. Note that the only thing not replaceable is .net core, I have a lot of experience in the dotnet world and I don't want to learn a new language for this project.