# Style attribute has no suggest in .vue files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs2

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/223

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1678

If files.associations: "* .vue": "vue", the page will lose its vue characteristics, after all, it is not an html page.
If you don't render the page according to html, then there is no code segment with embedded style.

Is it possible to have a style snippet while rendering according to vue

Answer (score 0):

Please see attached link for your answer

[*.vue files, Visual Studio 2017 & TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623643/vue-files-visual-studio-2017-typescript)

and see also best extensions for vue files in visual studio code

https://flaviocopes.com/vue-vscode/